# Web-pack only transpiling the entry point js file but not the rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hey guys I'm setting my development server and I would like webpack to search through each .js file and transpiled them using babel. As is currently set up, my bundle.js only includes the content of my entry point but not other js file in the project directory. any tips ?

this is my webpack config

```
module.exports = {

    entry: './app/src/index.js',
    output:{
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath:'/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer:{
        inline: true,
        contentBase:'./',
        port: 61116

    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:  /\.js$/,
                exclude:/(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"]
                } 
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader:"style-loader!css-loader"
            },
             {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader:"html-loader"

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is my folder structure

[image]

**Entry Point index.js**

```
import React from 'react' ;
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log("This ran");
const  App = () =>{
    return (<p>This is a new app</p>);
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector(".react-container"));
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your entry point "index.js" file?

Comment: Added the index.js, those changes do come up on the bundles .js but changes to other .js files nothing gets added to bundle.js

Comment: Your _index.js_ file isn't actually using any of your React/Redux code yet. Try defining a `TestComponent.jsx` in your _components_ dir, then importing into your entry point _index.js_ file and using it. `const App = () => (<div><TestComponent /><p>This is a new app</p></div>);`

Comment: no import errors, but no extra code is added to bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IsenrichO implies in the comments, you don't seem to be including "index.js" from your components folder. Any file that is not first imported by the entry point, or any file the entry point imports, and so on, will not be transpiled.

Try `import IndexComponent from "./components/index";`, or whatever the name of your index component class is.

Comment: That was the issue, since I was not importing them into the entry point. They got ignored.